Some a-frame gltf entities are loading fully black or grey; Texture Bug? Or is it a light problem?
Im using some models from ScketchLab and two of them have no texture/color. One is fully grey and the other one is black
 <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/c-frame/aframe-extras@7.5.2/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a-scene>
      <!-- Gerenciamento de Assets do A-Frame -->
        <a-assets>
          <!-- Fundo e assets-->
          <img id="fundo" src="./texturas/material_emissive.png" />
          <a-assets-item id="ship" src="./assets/pixel_low_poly_spaceship/scene.gltf"></a-assets-item>
          <a-assets-item id="propulsion" src="./assets/simple_engine_plume_test/simple_engine_plume_test.glb"></a-assets-item>
          <a-assets-item id="hyperspeed" src="./assets/hyperspeed_starfield/scene.gltf"></a-assets-item>
          <a-assets-item id="tronicle" src="./assets/tronicle/scene.gltf"></a-assets-item>
          <a-assets-item id="glow" src="./assets/uttm_glow/scene.gltf"></a-assets-item>
          <a-assets-item id="light_beam" src="./assets/appearance_effect_light_beam/scene.gltf"></a-assets-item>


        </a-assets>

        <a-sky src="#fundo"></a-sky>
        <a-light type="ambient" color="#ffffff" intensity="1"></a-light>

        <a-entity
        rotation="-90 0 0"
        >
          <a-entity
          gltf-model="#light_beam"
          scale="10 10 10"
          position="0 0 0"
          ></a-entity>     
 
          <a-entity
          gltf-model="#glow"
          ></a-entity>

          <a-entity
          gltf-model="#tronicle"
          scale="1 1 1"
          rotation="90 0 0"
          glow="enabled:true"
          material="shader: standard;"
          animation-mixer="clip: Animation; loop: repeat; time-scale: 1;"
          ></a-entity>

        </a-entity>




        <a-entity
        gltf-model="#hyperspeed"
        scale="100 100 100"
        position="0 0 0"
        rotation="0 0 0"
        animation-mixer="clip: Starfield; loop: repeat; time-scale: 0.2;"
        ></a-entity>

        <!-- Modelo 3D da nave -->
        <a-entity 
        gltf-model="#ship"
        scale="2 2 2"
        position="0 0 -100"
        rotation="0 0 0"
        >

          <a-entity
          gltf-model="#propulsion"
          position="0 0.2 -0.75"
          rotation="-90 0 0"
          scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"
          animation-mixer="clip: Action; loop: repeat; time-scale: 1;"
          ></a-entity>

        </a-entity>

        <a-entity position="6 0 0" rotation="0 90 0">
          <a-camera></a-camera>
        </a-entity>

      </a-scene>
    </body>
    <script>
    </script>
  </html>

Here's how they should appear:
IMG1
IMG2
But the are like this:
RENDER1
RENDER2
Tried material properties and changing lights, buy it didn't work. I don't think its related to the animation-mixer because and i don't know if its really a glitch or i'm just doing something wrong. I  suppose its probably because of the glowing effect
